# Name for measure of non-injectivity of a covering map

Tags: notation, definition, covering-spaces

Suppose that $p:C\to X$ is a covering map.  For $x\in X$, is there a name for the number $Card(p^{-1}(x))$?

So that for $p(z)=z^5:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, one might say "The ***** of $w$ under $p$ is $5$".

Comment: ***** $=$ degree

Comment: $|p^{-1}(x)|$, if it's finite, is usually called the number of sheets of the cover. It's a fact that for any $x, y \in X$, $|p^{-1}(x)| = |p^{-1}(y)|$, so it's well-defined and a global property of the covering map $p$, instead of a local one, so you can replace "preimage of $w$ under $p$ is $5$" by "numbers of sheets of $p$ is $5$"

Comment: @BalarkaSen This is true regardless of the topology of the Riemann surfaceses $C$ and $X$?

Comment: @TrevorRichards I am not sure I understand you. The cardinality of the preimage depends only on the covering map $p$, and not on the choice of point you're taking preimage of. Since it depends on the covering map $p$, surely it depends on the base space and the covering space...

Comment: @BalarkaSen I am not asking about whether the number of sheets depends on the topology of the base space and the covering space, but whether the globalness of the number of sheets is true independent of topology.  For instance, if $X$ where the torus (instead of an annulus), and $C$ where some complicated covering space of $X$.

Comment: @Trevor I still don't know what you mean. By "globalness" of the number of sheets, I meant it's the same for every point in the base space, and doesn't differ locally by changing the point you're taking preimage of. Certainly the number of sheets of a cover over $B$ changes if you change the covering space sitting above (although there might exist nonequivalent covers with same number of sheets)

Comment: @BalarkaSen Thank you for clarifying, I just wanted to make sure that the fact that "$|p^{-1}(w)|$ is independent of $w$" did not depend on the simplicity of the example I gave.